# Using PostCSS and PurgeCSS in Gulp

Tags: npm, gulp, postcss

I'm just trying to use PurgeCSS in the simpliest way I can imagine. But I can't even do that!

This code doesn't give any error, and it does create a new CSS file in the dest folder, so Gulp is processing the function. But the CSS resulting file has the same unused styles than the first one.

Tried with gulp-purgecss:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var purgecss    = require('gulp-purgecss');

gulp.task('purgecss', function(){
    return gulp.src('dist/css/styles.css')
        .pipe(purgecss({
            content: ['dist/**/*.html']
        }))      
        .pipe(gulp.dest('min/css'));
});
```

And with PostCSS + PurgeCSS:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var postcss     = require('gulp-postcss');
var postcsspurgecss = require('@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss');

gulp.task('postPurge', function(){
    var postcssPlugins = [
        postcsspurgecss({
            content: ['**/*.html']
        })
    ];
    return gulp.src('dist/css/styles.css')
        .pipe(postcss(postcssPlugins))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('min/css'));
});
```

And actually, ideally I would like to use it with internal CSS. But any help with this standard approach would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide a minimal example of your CSS and HTML that is _not_ working as expected. Your gulp-purgecss attempt looks fine.

Comment: Hi @kram08980 - did you ever resolve this. Having the exact same problem. purgecss is running without error and outputting the stylesheet, but there are no changes to the source code and all unused styles remain in the doc.

Comment: I have the same case hope someone give a tips for it, thanks.